# css :checked doesn't work in IE on IIS 7 server

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, iis-7

I'm doing an image replace for my radios, it works local in IE(just opening the html page), on WAMP in IE and also on my Linux server online in IE but will not work on my in-house IIS 7 server. Works in Chrome on the IIS server but not IE.

HTML

```
<input id='Good' type='radio' class='css-checkbox'name='value' value='1'/>  
    <label  id='1' class='css-label' for='Good'> Good </label>
```

CSS

```
input[type=radio].css-checkbox {
    margin: 10px;
    display:none;
}
input[type=radio].css-checkbox + label.css-label {
    padding-left:27px;
    height:22px; 
    display:inline-block;
    line-height:22px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position: 0 0 !important;
    vertical-align:middle;
    cursor:pointer;
}
label.css-label {
    margin: 10px;
    background-image:url(../images/radio.png);
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
input[type=radio].css-checkbox:checked + label.css-label{
    background-position: 0 -22px !important;
}
```

Comment: do you get any error message? Quick guess : when a client functionality differs depending on the server, I most of the time look for a "compatibility mode" or "security mode" of the browser, that may be different depending you're on a local address or a distant one. This has nothing to do with the server, but the domain...

Comment: look at the "network" tab or your developer tools. My second guess would be a problem with the relative path to your image in the CSS (although I have no Idea why this would then work in Chrome...), but in that case it would show as 404 status in the network tab.

Comment: So it was a compatibility view issue. I went into "compatibility view settings" and unchecked "show intranet in compatibility view". Works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

So it was a compatibility view issue. I went into "compatibility view settings" and unchecked "show intranet in compatibility view". Works fine now.

Comment: Good, I knew it would be one of those things. Remember that ! That will save you a lot of time in the future ;-)